# Pandas create column based on values in other rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I am currently trying to add a new column in a pandas dataset whose data is based on the contents of other rows in the dataset.

In the example, for each row x, I want to find the entry from id_real from row y, so that the content of id_par in row x matches the content from id in row y. See the following example.

```
id_real id id_par
100     1  2      
200     2  3      
300     3  4   



id_real id id_par new_col 
100     1  2      200
200     2  3      300
300     3  4      NaN
```

I have tried a lot of things and the last thing I tried was the following:

```
df["new_col"] = df[df["id"] == df["id_par"]]["node_id"]
```

Unfortunately, the new column then only contains NaN entries. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to match the "id_par" using "id" as index and "id_real" as values:

```
df['new_col'] = df['id_par'].map(df.set_index('id')['id_real'])
```

output:

```
   id_real  id  id_par  new_col
0      100   1       2    200.0
1      200   2       3    300.0
2      300   3       4      NaN
```

Comment: I tried this, I than got: "pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Comment: this means you have duplicates, please provide a larger example and the expected output (there are many possibilities)

Comment: Thank you, how can you find the clashing duplicates? I have a big instance so I don't know where there are duplicates (Since I'm working with ID's there should be no duplicates at all...)

Comment: you can use `df['id'].value_counts()` for example to get them listed by count, or `df.loc[df['id'].duplicated(), 'id'].unique()`

Comment: If you want all combinations of duplicates, you can `merge`: `df.merge(df[['id', 'id_real']].rename(columns={'id_real': 'new_col'}), left_on='id_par', right_on='id', how='left', suffixes=('', '_')).drop(columns='id')`

Comment: Sorry, wrong answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael it's fine you can leave it I was about to update anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for match first `id` rows:

```
df["new_col"] = df['id_par'].map(df.drop_duplicates('id').set_index('id')['id_real'])
print (df)
   id_real  id  id_par  new_col
0      100   1       2    200.0
1      200   2       3    300.0
2      300   3       4      NaN
```

Comment: exact duplicate ;)

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, I than got: "pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Comment: @AddiPrinz - solution was changed by `df["new_col"] = df['id_par'].map(df.drop_duplicates('id').set_index('id')['id_real'])`